# How to trigger code in separate sheet to run, using code in current sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code here and what the code around it does is not important, it runs properly. However at the point highlighted I need to trigger code in the "SCP Status Paynter" sheet I point to, to get triggered to run BEFORE the code below that point. I dont want to just put in another button or something I just want it to hit that point in the code and run the code in that other sheet. Havent been able to specifically find what I need on google and im new to this so im not sure what to do. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If it's not in an event, you can just call it like any other sub or function 
`SubroutineName (parameter1, parameter2...)`.
If it is in an event, put it in a sub or function and have the event call that sub or function that way other subs can call it.

Comment: make sure that your sub/function is declared public and in a module.

Comment: You can actually call public subroutines from worksheet objects as long as you prefix the subroutine with the object name. `Sheet1.SubroutineName()` would work, and because `Sub` and `Function` is implicitly `Public` within the project unless specified otherwise, there's no need to add the prefix. That being said, for best practices, it probably should be in a module.

Comment: @TateGarringer Why would putting it in a module be the best practice? A Worksheet is a class, and the user code behind it basically forms an additional interface - `Sheet1` is a `Worksheet` that implements the interface defined by the user code, so defining a `Public Sub` there is essentially just extending the class.

Comment: I usually try to have generic code being called from a number of other sheets/modules in a generic module as opposed to an object just for cleaner looking code. That way I'm not specifying an object name behind every call. It just looks nicer.

Comment: @TateGarringer - I think the key there is "generic code", and I'd agree that likely belongs in a module.  If it's specific to the worksheet though, I generally prefer that it is tied to the sheet explicitly.

Comment: @TateGarringer, it's also much easier to understand if another developer is debugging your code.Keeping your functions and subs "in scope" so that code that applies only the worksheet is all that's in the worksheet module is simply smart coding.  If it's code that is accessed from multiple sheets, it's best to put it in it's own intelligently named module.  In most cases don't use the default module names, name them using something that indicates what the code in them is used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VBE's *Project Explorer* is making it rather hard to tell/guess what specific procedure you intend to invoke ([Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck)'s *Code Explorer* drilling down to procedure-level nodes would have helped here! Note: I'm one of the admins on this open-source project), but anyway it looks like you need to invoke a procedure located in the `Sheet1` document module.

Say your procedure looks like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

Then from anywhere in your project, you can do this:

```
Sheet1.DoSomething
```

Which isn't any different than when you do this:

```
MsgBox "hello, world"
```

That's invoking a public/global-scope function located in a standard library function, whose fully-qualified name would be:

```
VBA.Interaction.MsgBox "hello, world"
```

Now, if your procedure looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

Then you have a problem: it's `Private`, and it's an event handler. Event handlers *can* be made `Public` and invoked as above, however a better practice would be to pull the body into a separate procedure, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
    DoSomething
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething()
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

That way you leave event handlers alone. Worksheet event handers are meant to be invoked by Excel, not user code; the same applies to e.g. `CommandButton1_Click` handlers: they're meant to be `Private` and invoked by the MSForms library, not by user code. Making it a habit of implementing logic outside of event handlers (and make them *invoke* the logic instead), is a very good habit to take early on.

Comment: Where/how do you learn about the standard library stuff, i.e. how'd you know it's `VBA.Interaction.MsgBox`? That's a really excellent point you made!

Comment: @BruceWayne hit F2 :-)